# How to find the 1st and 3rd Sunday/Monday of a current month in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Can anyone help me to find the specific week day of the month in postgresql... like 1st and 3rd week sunday/monday or 2nd and 4th week wednesday

Comment: Please edit your question, provide data source and desired resuld

Answer (score 1):

First off contrary to initial expectations working with dates is complex, sometime extremely so. The combination of week numbers and days the week fall into the latter category.  
The problem stems from the 2 ISO definitions:

- All weeks start on Monday and are 7 days long.
- The first week of the year is the week containing 4-Jan.

This dooms any effort (at least any reasonable simple onc) to failure. While an admirable effort I'll use @Abelisto suggestion as a sample. [See Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cpDFoMEHxaK6YkS7sb7bzL/1).   I've changed that just enough to use multiple parameters, while for most months it's correct but look at 30,31-Jan-2019 and Jan-2021.
The problem with the first being while the ISO week is perfectly consistent the calendar is not.  This results that the first week of a given month be the same as the last week of the previous month, and the reverse.
While this can usually be worked around by itself not so when combined with the other. As a result of each being 7 days long and the 1st week of the year containing 4-Jan gives rise to the larger problem. The last few days of Dec maybe in the 1st week of the next year. Also the first days of Jan can be in the 52( or 53) week of the prior year (see 2nd query in fiddle). Is there a solution? I'm sure there is somewhere out there. I just don't have it. At least with the Extract function.  
So how about this specific issue: Well basically it comes down to getting the last day of the previous month, then finding the next DOW (Sunday or Monday) as needed. Now coming from a Oracle back ground I'd just use the NEXT_DAY function which would do just that for me. Unfortunately Postgres does not provide that useful function. But you can roll your own. Below I provide a a couple functions I wrote to do this functionality in Postgres. It consists of 2 Postgres SQL functions:  
 
 - utl_dates_first_dow_of_month(). It takes 2 parameters, the target Day-Of-Week (DOW) as the first 3 characters of the day name (case insensitive) and a date in the desired month. It returns the DATE which is the first occurrence of the requested DOW.  
 - utl_dates_next_dow(). It takes the same 2 parameters and returns the next calendar date of the specified DOW from the from the specified date. If the date specified fall on the requested DOW the routine DOES NOT return the specified date. Function is actually used by the first.  
Fortunately the routines are shorter than the description.

```
create or replace function utl_dates_next_dow(dow_in text, date_in date)
 returns   date
 language  sql
 immutable strict  
as $$
-- Given a DOW and a date return the calendar date for the next occurrence of DOW
with dy as (select string_to_array('mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun', ',') dl)
   , dn as (select array_position(dl, (substring(to_char(date_in, 'day'),1,3))) fn  
                 , array_position(dl, lower(substring(dow_in,1,3)))             dn
              from dy 
           )
select case when dn <= fn
            then (date_in + (dn+7-fn) * interval '1 day')::date 
            else (date_in + (dn-fn)   * interval '1 day')::date
       end 
  from dn; 
$$;

create or replace function utl_dates_first_dow_of_month(dow_in text, date_in date)
 returns   date
 language  sql
 immutable strict  
as $$
-- Given a DOW and a Date return the calendar date of the first specified dow in which the specified date falls.
select utl_dates_next_dow(dow_in,  (date_trunc('month', date_in) - interval '1 day')::date);
$$;
```

Now with that out out of the way on the the issue at hand.  As Abelisto, and others, indicate the request is ambiguous. There is no such thing as 1st or 3rd Sunday/Monday. Do you want the 1st and 3rd Sunday and the 1st and 3rd Monday of the month? Do you want
Do you want the 1st and 3rd Sunday of the month and the Monday following each respectively. Do you want the Sunday and Monday for the 1st and 3rd week on the month (If so Monday would always be the earlier date, see definition 1 above)? Please try to be more specific with your questions. And include test data - **as text no images** - and the expected results from that data.  The solutions are however just slight modifications of each other. (No solution for the 3rd listed possibility.)

For the case of 1st and 3rd Sunday and the 1st and 3rd Monday:

```
with parms (dt) as (values ( date '2020-04-01'), (date '2020-06-01') )
   , base_dates( fsun, fmon) as 
     ( select utl_dates_first_dow_of_month('Sun',dt) 
            , utl_dates_first_dow_of_month('Mon',dt)
         from parms
     ) 
select '1st & 3rd Sunday and 1st & 3rd Monday' 
     , fsun   "1st Sunday"
     , (fsun+interval '14 days')::date "3rd Sunday"     
     , fmon   "1st Monday"
     , (fmon+interval '14 days')::date "3rd Monday" 
  from base_dates;
```

For the 1st and 3rd Sunday of the month and the Monday following:

```
with parms (dt) as (values ( date '2020-04-01'), (date '2020-06-01') )
   , base_dates( fsun, fmon) as 
     ( select utl_dates_first_dow_of_month('Sun',dt)
            , (utl_dates_first_dow_of_month('Sun',dt)+interval '1 day')::date  
         from parms
     ) 
select '1st & 3rd Sunday and Monday Following '  
     , fsun   "1st Sunday"
     , fmon   "1st Monday"
     , (fsun+interval '14 days')::date "3rd Sunday"
     , (fmon+interval '14 days')::date "3rd Monday" 
  from base_dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(
    select dow, i, row_number() over(partition by dow order by i) as rnk from
    (
        select 
            extract(dow from i::date) as dow, 
            i::date 
        from generate_series('2022-10-01'::date,'2022-10-31'::date,interval '1 Day') i
    ) tmp where dow = 1
)tmp_out where rnk = 3;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).